# pom.xml file is showing these yellow color warnings in IntelliJIDEA while I can run the project just fine

Tags: appium, pom.xml, guava, java-15, apache-commons-collection

I am using Appium 2.0.0-beta66, Java Client 8.5.0, node 18.xx, Selenium-java 4.9.1, Selenium Server 3.141.59, TestNG 7.7.1, and JDK 1.15.0-02, what is the next long term JDK I can go for ?

BTW, I am seeing these yellow color highlights in pom.xml file with warnings like ...

1. Provides transitive vulnerable dependency maven:commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.2 Cx78f40514-81ff 7.5 Uncontrolled Recursion vulnerability pending CVSS allocation Cx78f40514-81ff 7.5 Uncontrolled Recursion vulnerability pending CVSS allocation  Results powered by Checkmarx(c)
2. Provides transitive vulnerable dependency maven:org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.19 CVE-2017-18640 7.5 Improper Restriction of Recursive Entity References in DTDs ('XML Entity Expansion') vulnerability pending CVSS allocation CVE-2022-25857 7.5 Uncontrolled Resource Consumption vulnerability pending CVSS allocation CVE-2022-38752 6.5 Out-of-bounds Write vulnerability with medium severity found CVE-2022-38749 6.5 Out-of-bounds Write vulnerability pending CVSS allocation CVE-2022-38750 5.5 Out-of-bounds Write vulnerability pending CVSS allocation CVE-2022-38751 6.5 Out-of-bounds Write vulnerability pending CVSS allocation CVE-2022-41854 6.5 Out-of-bounds Write vulnerability with medium severity found CVE-2022-1471 9.8 Deserialization of Untrusted Data vulnerability with high severity found  Results powered by Checkmarx(c)
3. Provides transitive vulnerable dependency maven:com.google.guava:guava:25.0-jre CVE-2020-8908 3.3 Incorrect Permission Assignment for Critical Resource vulnerability pending CVSS allocation  Results powered by Checkmarx(c)

```
Here is my pom.xml file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.zimperium</groupId>
    <artifactId>zMTD</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>15</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>15</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>15</source>
                        <target>15</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <suiteXmlFiles>
                            <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                        </suiteXmlFiles>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
            <version>8.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json 20210307-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20220320</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.rest-assured/rest-assured -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.rest-assured/json-path (new) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.json/javax.json-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.zxing/core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.zxing/javase -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
            <artifactId>javase</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/me.jvt.cucumber/reporting-plugin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>me.jvt.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>reporting-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>7.11.0</version>
<!--            <version>7.0.0</version>-->
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-server -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.7.1</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

</project>
```

**How do I make those warning go away ?**

Comment: If at all possible, take these warnings seriously as they indicate that your project has security vulnerabilities that can be fixed by upgrading your dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

You can click on the light bulb next to the warning, the first option should be: `inspection <your warning> options`. Click on that and you can choose suppress all warnings in file, or whatever works best for your case.

You can read more [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/disabling-and-enabling-inspections.html#suppress-inspections).

But before suppressing these warnings, they exist in the first place for a reason, do your due diligence and decide afterwards if you want to suppress them or fix them.